# FormHelper and Hash as Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use Hash object like as ActiveRecord Model within FormHelper:

```
<% hash = { :some_key => 'some_value' } %>

<% fields_for "hash", hash do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :some_key %>

<% end %>
```

As far as I know, its trying to call :some_key method for hash object. I was trying to override 'send' method for Hash class but have no luck:

```
def send( symbol, args = [] )
  if self.has_key?( symbol )
    self[ symbol ]
  elsif self.has_key?( symbol.to_s )
    self[ symbol.to_s ]
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Have you any ideas how could I play with this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're looking in a Hash with symbols as keys, for a string. That's not going to work. But I'm not really sure this is a good idea anyway, although I can't point to why exactly...

Comment: ah... you'r right. That is my fault. That's because I'm sure that I have my keys as strings. Changed example as well. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using [`OpenStruct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) or [`Struct`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html) instead of `Hash`?

Comment: Never heard about that. Looks like exactly what I needed. Will try. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to [KL-7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357743/kl-7) for his proposition of OpenStruct. So, if someone need this, I'm adding here full working example.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  HASH_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT = {
    :value => '',
    :selected => 0
  }

  serialize :hash_attribute, Hash

  def hash_attribute
    read_attribute( :hash_attribute ) || HASH_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULT
  end

  def hash_attribute=( hash )
    write_attribute( :hash_attribute, hash ) unless hash.nil?
  end

end
```

And now it's time for OpenStruct:

```
<% fields_for "model[hash_attribute]", OpenStruct.new( @model.hash_attribute ) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :value %>
  <%= f.check_box :selected %>

<% end %>
```